Generic function property arguments
I am using Zustand and have a generic modal store. I will create a store for each store. And the thing is that not all modals have props so I'd like the open function can be called without arguments like reviewModalStore.getState().open() (no args needed).
With the current code, the open function still needs undefined to work (see the last 2 lines).
import { create } from "zustand"

export type ModalStoreState<T> = {
    isOpen: boolean
    props: T | undefined
    open: (props: T) => void
    close: () => void
}

export const createModalStore = <T>() =>
    create<ModalStoreState<T>>()((set) => ({
        isOpen: false,
        props: undefined,
        open(props) {
            set((state) => ({
                ...state,
                props,
                isOpen: true,
            }))
        },
        close() {
            set((state) => ({
                ...state,
                isOpen: false,
                props: undefined,
            }))
        },
    }))

const reviewModalStore = createModalStore()
const openReviewModalStore = reviewModalStore.getState().open(undefined)

Thank you in advance!

Make props optional than

• Since the question isn't about zustand you might want to [edit] to make a [mre] without reference to it. Something simple enough like the Q part of this playground link (where the A part is the suggested answer). • Given these types and not knowing anything about zustand, if I take the A part of that playground code and translate it here I get this playground link. Does that suffice? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (but would really prefer having it be pure TS without zustand). If not, what am I missing?
